# How Iterate all elements of tabs from csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, csv

I write some code like this:

```
require 'csv'
people = CSV.parse(File.read("import1.csv")) 
puts people[0][0]
puts people[0][1]
puts people[0][2]
```

How can I now read all elements from people??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve. Could you expand on what you're trying to do?  Have you thought about parsing each row in the file in turn and hence operating on each person individually?  e.g.

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |person|
  first_name = person[0]
  last_name = person[1]
  # ... do something with the person - add to an array, construct a Person object etc      
end
```

And, if you have headers, just include the `:headers => true` option like so:

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv", :headers => true) do |person|
  first_name = person[0]
  last_name = person[1]
  # ... do something with the person - add to an array, construct a Person object etc      
end
```

Comment: OK It looks good , but I have a problem that the first rows are the name of colums ( my script has to check if the name of colums are correct too).

Comment: No problemo - I've edited to show you how to skip the header row :-)